# NullPointerException in Radiogroup

Tags: java, android, gridview, radio-button, android-custom-view

I am getting null pointer exception when i click add button.

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Bitmap bm = null;
// Declare Variables
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private RadioButton qtyselbut, timeselbut;
private List<Pojo> list = null;
private ArrayList<Pojo> arraylist;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Pojo> list) {
    mContext = context;
    this.list = list;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<Pojo>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(list);
}

private Resources getResources() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    TextView productname, product_name, product_price;
    TextView description;
    ImageView img1;
    TextView price;
    Button custom, add;
    RelativeLayout img, relatve, abve_lyt;
    LinearLayout radio;
    RadioGroup qtygroup, timegrp;
    RadioButton groupchecked;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Pojo getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridimg, null);
        // Locate the TextViews in listview_item.xml
        holder.productname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.productname);
        holder.product_name = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.product_name);
        holder.description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        holder.img1 = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
        holder.product_price = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.product_price);
        holder.custom = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.customize);
        holder.relatve = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relavelyt);
        holder.radio = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        holder.qtygroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.qty_text);
        /* holder.button1 = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.radibuttt0); */
        holder.abve_lyt = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.above_layt);
        holder.add = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Add_item);
        holder.timegrp = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.time_text);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.productname.setText(list.get(position).getProductname());
    holder.description.setText(list.get(position).getDescription());
    holder.price.setText(list.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.product_price.setText(list.get(position).getPrice());
    holder.product_name.setText(list.get(position).getProductname());
    /*
     * holder.button1.setOnCheckedChangeListener((OnCheckedChangeListener)this
     * ); holder.button1.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
     */

    Log.i("", "" + holder.productname.getText().toString());
    Log.i("", "" + holder.description.getText().toString());
    Log.i("", "" + holder.price.getText().toString());
    // holder.img1.setImageBitmap(DownloadFullFromUrl(list.get(position).getImg1()));
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = DownloadFullFromUrl(list.get(position).getImg1());
    Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBitmap);
    holder.relatve.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

    // RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(mContext);
    // radioButton.setText(" Roasted Tomato");
    // radioButton.setText(" Red Chilli");
    // radioButton.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.customizeradiobutton);
    // holder.radio.addView(radioButton);

    holder.relatve.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent bv = new Intent(mContext, ViewpagerActivity.class);
            bv.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            mContext.startActivity(bv);

            // v.getContext().startActivity(mContext,ViewpagerActivity.class);

        }
    });



    holder.custom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            holder.abve_lyt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    });

    holder.add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String hj = holder.product_name.getText().toString();
            Log.d("sucess or failed", "" + hj);

            MainActivity.adapter.add(hj);
            MainActivity.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            int selectedId = holder.qtygroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            // find the radiobutton by returned id
            qtyselbut = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(selectedId);

            String yh = qtyselbut.getText().toString();

            Log.d("qtyselectdtext", "" + yh);

            int selectedid2 = holder.timegrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            timeselbut = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(selectedid2);

            String yhd = timeselbut.getText().toString();

            Log.d("timeselectdtext", "" + yhd);

        }
    });



    return view;
}

public Bitmap DownloadFullFromUrl(String imagess) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imagess);
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bm);
        View view = null;
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(baf.toByteArray(), 0,
                baf.toByteArray().length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
    }
    return bm;
}
```

}`

Comment: please provide the log. This is important for anybody to avoid the *guessing* business :)

Answer (score 0):

you must get NPE on:

```
String yh = qtyselbut.getText().toString();
```

because `qtyselbut` is null.

in bellow line

```
qtyselbut = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(selectedId);
```

`v` refer to your button ( `holder.add` ), you need your parent view instead of `v`, you must use `holder` object for getting value on layout

another thing that I see in your code is

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
```

don't use this, instead of that use `AsycTask` class or `Handler`

**// Update**

new problem occurred because following line

```
 int selectedId = holder.qtygroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

`holder` is not holder that you want, you can do your job with set `CheckedRadioButtonId` to tag of your button in getView method like:

```
  holder.add.setTag(yourValue);
```

then in button click you can use:

```
  int selectedId = (Integer)v.getTag();
```

Comment: i changed view instead of v, but now also i'm getting nullpointer exception

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mu40r6lybt58mbf/Screenshot%20from%202014-05-10%2012%3A37%3A08.png

Comment: indicate line 196 @ `ListAdapter`

Comment: what i want is.... each grid item have one radio group. when i click add button. i want to get selected radio text from appropriate grid item

Comment: did you try `view.findViewById()` instead of `v.findViewById()`;? you need change `view` to final

Comment: ya i got answer, but i didnt get appropriate griditem radiobutton value

Comment: see my Update and if this solved your problem tick that as answer

Answer (score 0):

I feel this section is responsible for Exception

```
          qtyselbut = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(selectedId);
            String yh = qtyselbut.getText().toString();
        Log.d("qtyselectdtext", "" + yh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `holder.relatve.setOnClickListener` to `view.relatve.setOnclickListener`and check it.

Answer (score 0):

// try this way,hope this will help you...

Under add button click listener this code make problem becz your are trying to find RadioButton v.findViewById() here v represent button view not parent layout so can you please comment this code and check what happens

```
   int selectedId = holder.qtygroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
   // find the radiobutton by returned id
   qtyselbut = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(selectedId);
   String yh = qtyselbut.getText().toString();
   Log.d("qtyselectdtext", "" + yh);
   int selectedid2 = holder.timegrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
   timeselbut = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(selectedid2);
   String yhd = timeselbut.getText().toString();
    Log.d("timeselectdtext", "" + yhd);
```